# Decimal point acting bad - ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

Tags: python, pandas, floating-point, typeerror, valueerror

I have SP500 data downloaded from the Fed, a very simple .csv file with two fields; date and price. When I do a `pd.read_csv()` to load into a dataframe I get two errors:

> TypeError: Cannot cast array from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'
>
> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '.'

It seems to be telling me that the decimal point '.' in the price field is throwing the error.

I have many files that handle the decimal point when converting a string object to a float.

here is the  data being used:

```
observation_date,price
2008-04-04,1340.40
2008-04-07,1372.54
2008-04-08,1365.54
2008-04-09,1354.49
2008-04-10,1360.55
2008-04-11,1332.83
2008-04-14,1328.32
2008-04-15,1334.43
2008-04-16,1364.71
```

I have also used:

```
SP500 = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
```

to load the file give both fields as object dtype
then using

```
SP500.price = SP500.price.astype(float).fillna(0.0)
```

this throws the same two errors

Comment: I can't reproduce, it reads in fine for me.

Comment: When I key in the data to a .csv file using notepad it works fine. but the downloaded csv file from the Federal Reserve throws the error. The data example I provided is after first loading the original Fed. data allowing pandas to used dtype Object for both fields, then do a db.to_csv(file_csv, decimal='.', index=False, sep=',')  to wrter the dataframe to a new csv file, giving the data format shown in the post. However, this new csv file still throws the two errors. Could there be some type of hidden characters  from the original data being writing out by the pd.to_csv() command.

Comment: here is the link to download the SP500 csv file https://fred.stlouisfed.org/series/SP500   use the download button then choose csv file. I have tried 4 other feb files, they all give the same error when trying to load price data as float fields. the decimal point in the fields throws the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try specifying that `'.'` is a `NaN` value

```
SP500 = pd.read_csv('SP500.csv', na_values=['.'])
```

Comment: That WORKS!<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 2609 entries, 0 to 2608
Data columns (total 2 columns):
observation_date    2609 non-null object
price               2518 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 40.8+ KB